# Program doesn't work as single and noconsole exe file (Pyinstaller)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I made a program with python and I want to turn it into an .exe file. I typed that command from the command prompt (cmd):

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole script.py
```

I used Tkinter in my script. When I run the .exe file, a window didn't appear.
How can I solve it?

@Charitoo I'm using Windows 7 32bit, Python 2.7.3

Comment: source code is missing?

Comment: @rahul tyagi It's not clear that where is the error in the program. So, I don't want to publish my source codes and when I remove one of these commands (--onefile and --noconsole), the problem solves. But I want to use both of them.

Comment: @python_pardus Your program is probably throwing an error, but you can't see it. Use a `try`-`except` and log the traceback to see what's happening when using those options.

Comment: @cdonts No, It hasn't throwen any error.

Comment: @cdonts Sorry, It has throwen error. But my program couldn't write error to file. It could create file but It couldn't write anything. I couldn't understand reason of this issue(It  couldn't write).

Comment: @python_pardus How are you logging errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem, because I could understand the reason for it.
I was using this code in my Python script:

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("chcp 1254", shell=True)
```

I deleted these codes and my problem was solved.

These codes were the reason for the problem, because I was creating an exe file which doesn't have a console screen, but I was using a command which tries to access the command line. Therefore, my program was closing. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: if not subprocess.check_output() then what should we use? subprocess.Popen() or subprocess.call()? and how?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed script.py
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: @python_pardus can you give more information about your development environment. python version, os, etc

Comment: try saving your script with a .pyw extension instead of .py extension

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 32bit, Python 2.7.3

Comment: I tried saving my script with a .pyw extension but It didn't work either.

Comment: what version of _PyInstaller_ are you using. Check the module using you imported or used to see if they are all supported by PyInstaller. Try reading the PyInstaller wiki. You might find the answer to why it is not working.

Comment: check this out [--onefile issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile?rq=1)